# How can you check if a column in a DataFrame is stale?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the fastest way to query for staleness (unvarying data) in a DataFrame column, so that it would return the 'Stale' column?

As example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import randn

df = DataFrame(randn(50, 5))
df['Stale'] = 100.0
```

will yield a df similar to the following:

```
      0         1         2         3         4         Stale
0 -0.064293  1.226319 -1.162909 -0.574240 -0.547402     100.0
1  0.529428  0.587148  0.367549  0.066041 -0.071709     100.0
2 -0.112633  0.217315  0.810061 -0.610718  0.179225     100.0
3  0.513706 -2.300195 -0.895974  0.853926 -1.604018     100.0
4  0.410546  0.641980  0.611272  1.121002 -1.082460     100.0
```

And I'd like to get the 'Stale' column returned. Right now I am doing: 
`df.columns[df.std() == 0.0]` which works, but which is probably not very efficient.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you want the Stale column, just do `df['Stale']`.

Comment: well I don't know this in advance. I am working with very large data sets and  I want to know what columns contain only stale data, so that I can remove them before applying calculations on them. The code I provided was only to create an example of a hypothetical situation

Comment: I still don't get it though.  What do you mean by "stale"?  In your exaple you just created a column called "Stale" and asked how to get it.  In your actual data, how do *you* (the human) know what data you are considering stale?

Comment: I think I may have answered your question, if so, please accept.

Comment: Agree with @BrenBarn that you need to define for us a little more what you mean by "stale".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
df.columns[df.std() == 0.0]
```

returns the 'Stale' index because the standard deviation of the stale column would be zero.

If you define "staleness" as unvarying data, `df.var() == 0` is slightly faster (probably because you don't need to take the square root). It also occurred to me to check `df.max() == df.min()` but that's actually slower.

To return the column using this information, do this:

```
df[df.columns[df.var() == 0.0]]
```

Comment: ok that's basically what I had then, except for the sqrt transformation from Var to Std. Is there no better Pandas way to find the column with unvarying data?

Comment: @Muppet I can't think of one, and I've spent a lot of time reviewing the DataFrame source, and I just scanned it one more time with this purpose in mind, but I can't think of anything so far, except for slow reductions, or perhaps a manager object that watches the data as it goes in, but in any trivial example it would be much slower, I think, and you'd need your full scale usage to demonstrate a performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if 'Stale' in df.columns: #test if you have a column named 'Stale'
    _df = df.ix[:,df.columns!='Stale']
    #do something on the DataFrame without the 'Stale' column
else:
    #_df = df
    #do something to the DataFrame directly.
```

You have the following options that I can think of:

`df.ix[:,df.columns!='Stale']` will return a view of the DataFrame without the `'Stale'` column and

`df.ix[:,df.columns=='Stale']` will return `'Stale'` column as a `DataFrame`, if it is in the dataframe. An empty `DataFrame` otherwise.

`df.get['Stale']` returns `'Stale'` column as a `Series`, if the column is not there, it will return `None`.

You can't just do `df['Stale']`, because if the column is not there, an `keyError` will be raised.

Comment: The OP does not want to detect columns with the literate column name 'Stale', see the comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the shift method of the pandas data frame:

```
     df == df.shift()
```

Note: almost never comment on stackoverflow.